# Issue with jQuery $.get in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a login form which appears at the top of all of my pages when the user is logged out.  My current jQuery/javascript code works in Firefox 3 but not IE 7.  The code queries a page which simply returns the string "true" or "false" depending on whether the login was successful or not.  Inside my $.ready() function call I have the following...

```
$('#login_form').submit(function() {

        var email = $('input#login_email').val();
        var pw = $('input#login_password').val()

        $.get('/user/login.php', { login_email: email, login_password: pw }, function(data) {
            alert('get succeeded');
            if(data == 'true') {
                $('#login_error').hide();
                window.location = '/user/home.php';
                alert('true');
            }
            else {
                $('#login_error').show();
                alert('false');
            }

        });

        alert('called');

        return false;
    });
```

In FF, I am successfully transferred to the intended page.  In IE, however, the below alerts "called" and nothing else.  When I refresh the page, I can see that I am logged in so the $.get call is clearly going through, but the callback function doesn't seem like its being called (ie. "get succeeded" is not popping up).  I also don't appear to be getting any javascript error messages either.

Why isn't this working in IE?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Since a couple people asked, whenever I enter a correct email/password or an incorrect one, nothing in the callback function happens.  If I manually refresh the page after entering a correct one, I am logged in.  Otherwise, I am not.

**EDIT 2:** If I alert out `data` in the callback function nothing happens in IE (I do not get an alert popup).  In FF, it alerts `true` for valid email/pw combos and `false` for invalid ones.  I am using jQuery 1.3.2.

**EDIT 3:** Ok, guys, I tried R. Bemrose's thing down there and I'm getting a "parseerror" on the returned data.  I'm simply echoing 'true' or 'false' from the other PHP script.  I also tried 'yes' and 'no', but that still gave me a parse error.  Also, this works in Chrome in addition to FF.

Comment: is your code being compressed, by chance? This is probably NOT the problem, but you are missing a semicolon on the end of line this line: var pw = $('input#login_password').val() and if your code was being minified before it got to the client, maybe IE's parser isn't able to make sense of things, but FF is doing it.

Comment: Nope, no compression being done.  Adding the semi-colon makes no difference.

Comment: Do email and pw have a valid value?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: what happens when you alert(data); in ie 7 ?

Comment: btw, I see my answer is getting downvoted now, but I was half serious. I ran your code on IE 7.0.5730.13 using jQuery 1.3.2, and it works like a charm.  Bottom line, the problem is not your code.

Comment: Have you used a tool like Fiddler to see what is being returned from the server with the XHR call?

Comment: This is really odd, apparently this code is working on some installations but not on all?  Something odd is afoot...

Comment: Could have something to do with the content type or other headers being sent back from the server's response. When I tested your JavaScript, I obviously didn't have your server-side code.

Comment: Have you tried it from IE on a different client?

Comment: @NVRAM - Yes, I have tried it on different machines.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone!!! :D  Stack Overflow rules!

Comment: Can someone give my answer below one more downvote?  I'm being serious.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your response type use:

header("content-type:application/xml;charset=utf-8");

Comment: Actually, I ended up using 

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

But the idea is the same.

Comment: I think IE has issues with certain response types, but cool that that works as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

As stupid as this sounds... perhaps IE7 is being anal retentive about the missing semicolon on the `var pw` line?

Probably not, but the only way I can think of getting more information is to convert it to an $.ajax call in order to add an error hook and see which error type it think is happening.  Oh, and to check out the exception object.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/user/login.php',
        data: { login_email: email, login_password: pw },
        success: function(data) {
                alert('get succeeded');
                if(data == 'true') {
                        $('#login_error').hide();
                        window.location = '/user/home.php';
                        alert('true');
                }
                else {
                        $('#login_error').show();
                        alert('false');
                }
        },
        error: function(xhr, type, exception) {
                alert("Error: " + type);
        }
});
```

If the error type is parse, IE may be complaining because the data coming back has extra commas at the end of comma separated arrays/lists.

Answer (score 1):

IE uses cached data for get requests. Maybe that's your problem? What happens if you try different user id, password?

In any case, isn't it a better idea to send password in POST? :)

Comment: Indeed, a post probably makes more sense so I changed it to that. But, the log in IS successful when using correct data, it's just that nothing in the callback function is executed. When I refresh the page manually, I can see that I am now logged in.

If the username/password combination is incorrect, the "false" alert fails to appear as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm am having a similar problem with the following code:

```
var listOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
var otherVariable = whatever
$.get('process_todo.cfm?method=sortToDos', {listOrder:listOrder,otherVariable :otherVariable });
```

The variable displays through an alert as 'test_123,test_456'.  I can hard code the same values and it does not fail.  It must have something to do with the 'toArray'?  I have been trying to debug this one thing for hours.  Works perfectly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome... of course!

Comment: What TORTURE!!!  Finally, the issue is solved.  Fake out IE caching by appending the time as a parameter on the get url:           var sDate = new Date()                              $.get('process_todo.cfm?method=sortToDos&' + sDate.getTime(), ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

if(data == 'true')

try:

if(data)

then in your server just return either a 1 (or true) and a empty value.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I changed login.php to return 1 or an empty string like you said and it no longer errors for incorrect email/pw combinations.

Comment: Then I'd say your problem is on the server side php code.  Use firebug or fiddler to see what's coming back.

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted (at least after Edit 2) looks good.  I think the problem is in what you *haven't* posted.

First, have you checked your server logs to ensure that it's sending back what you presume?

If so, I'd recommend dropping the submit mechanism and using a 'button' type with an 'onclick' handler, and not 'submit' button w/a 'onsubmit' handler...

```
 <input type="button" id="login_submit" value="Login" />
```

Then switch the submit handler:

```
  $('#login_form').submit(function() { ... });
```

from the form to the button with:

```
  $('#login_button').click(function() { ... });
```

If that doesn't help, can you post the HTML for the form, too?

**[Edit 3]** - try adding the 4th 'type' parameter of "text" to the $.post() call.

Comment: It is indeed sending back what I presume.  I did use the parameter type of 'text', but it hasn't done anything.  I don't think it is an event problem either, as the submit event is most certainly being entered ('called' is being alerted if you take a look at the code).

Answer (score 0):

Have you used Fiddler to have a good look at what's actually being transferred?  (http://www.fiddler2.com)

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing/checking your script in local machine then you will not see any thing in any version of internet explorer because IE on localmachine send datatype as text and not xml and in your case again its matter of datatype not compatible with your document datatype so it worth checking if your datatypes are matching

as far as xml goes solution is here
http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

you may check this and find some inspiration :)

salman